# Bootstrap datetimepicker issue with year not selected correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using the bootstrap datetime picker to select a year. From a table when selecting a column I update the datetime picker with the selected year.  The picker shows the correct date of the selected item but when wanting to change the date it fails to show the selected value from the year selector when the year is outside the previous range of shown years. When closing it and opening it again, the year is now selected.

For example if I select first 2015 and after that 2016, it works fine because it's within the same range of displayed year values.  When I next time select for example 2001, nothing is selected. Closing and opening again will then select it.

I attached some code, however to run the code snippet, the "bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" CDN needs to be replaced with an edited version that fixes an issue where after closing the year view and opening it again it will revert to the day view. (see https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1850)

I fixed this in my code by commenting out line 'currentViewMode = 0' on line 937 but could not post the code as this would exceed the allowed character limit.

1. When first laoding the app and clicking the picker it has the current year selected:

[image]

2. When selecting another year from the table and open the year picker with the updated year, if it's within the range of values it selects it correctly:

[image]

3. However, when selecting a year not in the same range, when opening the picker, nothing is selected:

[image]

4. Yet, when closing the view (without clicking any year or anything else, just clicking outside of the view to close it) and opening it again, the corrrect year is now selected (and the year range correctly updated):

[image]

```js
$(function () {

    var table = $("#test-table")
        .DataTable(
        {
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
            "searching": false,
            "paginate": false
        });


    $("#test-table tbody")
        .on("click",
            "tr",
            function () {

                if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {

                    $(this).removeClass("selected").removeClass("selected");
                } else {

                    table.$("tr.selected").removeClass("selected").removeClass("selected");


                    var date = this.getElementsByClassName("date-value")[0].innerText;
                    var item1 = this.getElementsByClassName("item1-value")[0].innerText;

                    var dateArr = date.split(" ");
                    var year = dateArr[1];
                    var month = getMonth(dateArr[0]);
                    var day = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();                   

                    var m = moment(day + "." + (Number(month)) + "." + year, ["DD.MM.YYYY", "DD.MM.YYYY"]);
                    $("#yearPicker").data("DateTimePicker").date(m);

                    $("#Item1Val").val(item1);
                    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings();

                }
            });

    function getMonth(strMonth) {
        var months = [
            "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
            "November", "December"
        ];

        return months.indexOf(strMonth) + 1;


    }

    $("#button")
        .click(function () {

            table.row(".selected").remove().draw(false);
        });


    var decDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 11, 31);
    $("#yearPicker")
        .datetimepicker({
            viewMode: "years",
            format: "YYYY",
            defaultDate: decDate

        });


    $(function () {
        $("#yearPicker")
            .datetimepicker({
                defaultDate: new Date()
            })
            .on("dp.change",
                function () {
                    table.$("tr.selected").removeClass("selected");
                    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
                    $("#Item1Val").val(0);
                });

    });

});
```

```css
.datepicker {
    z-index: 1030;
}

.calendar-icon {
    width: inherit;
}

.table-striped tbody tr.selected td {
    background-color: #b0bed9
}

.alert-error {
    float: right;
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
    color: #b54f4f;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border: solid 2px #efc4c4;
    padding: 1.2em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    margin: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 15em;
    width: 50%;
}

.alert-error ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css"></script>



<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="home-page" class="row">
        <br/>
        <div class="test-data">
            <table id="test-table" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr><th class="date-col">Date</th><td>Values</td></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="date-value">
                                    <span class="hidden">2002</span>December 2002
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="test-values">
                                    <div class="hidden">
                                        44
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4">Item</div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 item1-value">44</div>
                                    </div>                                   
                                </div>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="date-value">
                                    <span class="hidden">2004</span>December 2004
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="test-values">
                                    <div class="hidden">
                                        4
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4">Item</div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 item1-value">4</div>
                                    </div>                                   
                                </div>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="date-value">
                                    <span class="hidden">2012</span>December 2012
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="test-values">
                                    <div class="hidden">
                                        0
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-4">Item</div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 item1-value">0</div>
                                    </div>                                   
                                </div>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
  <form action="/Home/AddChartData" method="post">            
   <div class="row">
    <br/>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="form-group">

      <div class='input-group date' id="yearPicker">
       <input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field yearPicker must be a date." data-val-required="The yearPicker field is required." name="yearPicker" type="text" class="form-control">
       <span class="input-group-addon calendar-icon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
       </span>

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div id="test-update-form">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-6">Item</div>
       <div class="col-lg-6"><input Value="0" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Item1Val must be a number." data-val-required="The Item is required" id="Item1Val" max="100" min="0" name="Item1Val" step=".01" type="number" value="0" /></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>      
   </div>
  </form>        
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.42/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-I8vGZkA2jL0PptxyJBvewDVqNXcgIhcgeqi+GD/aw34=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: it won't select unless you click on it. It seems that you want to see "typed" year on fly. which I think not possible.

Comment: It should select from the updated value.  It works correctly initially and on a second opening. Maybe I wasn't clear enough, the datetimepicker value is updated with whatever row is selected in the table.  The year updates correctly as can be seen from the value in the text box. It's the year picker view that doesn't update correctly on a first click, but does when opening it again (without having selected any value)#

Comment: This is what i am telling you. I am sure the change happens on "click" of year and not without it

Comment: It always works correctly when the year is one of the years on the range of years like between 2007-2018.  2007, 2008, 2009, etc, will correctly update, but not when it's in a previous or next range of dates.  However, closing it without doing anything and then opening it again, it will select the correct year within the correct year range.

Comment: Sounds like a defect because the default range it shows is based on current date than the range. And it applies the range after the first time closing. Could you create a plnkr with the date picker code pasted ASIS and reproduce it ?

Comment: The code is attached.

Comment: I created a plnkr here to demonstrate: https://plnkr.co/edit/JWtfXZxkzmiMUjOHNqYz